# Can a 1099 consultant receive unemployment benefits (EDD) after termination from a separate full time job?

Tags: united-states, self-employment, unemployment, consulting

My wife, on occasion, is called upon to consult at a former employer, which had been after hours with-respect-to her normal 9 to 5 job.  She was laid-off from her 9-5 job, however, she still gets called in to do 2 hours here and there, as a consultant at a former 9 to 5 job - I believe it would be termed - "consultant" and she gets 1099-R pay.

Can she apply for and receive unemployment?

I know that the forms and questions they ask have, from my point of view, ambiguous questions that if mis-answered, disqualify someone immediately.  Like "did the tooth-fairy leave $1 under your pillow last night?"  - Yes.  Red-flag!  Perform financial analysis for last 10 years to see if you qualify...  I just want to avoid any pitfalls and red tape that otherwise ends up at the same conclusion, albeit with less paperwork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unemployment is a state not federal program so it would be important to know what state you are in. For my state, [California](http://www.edd.ca.gov/Unemployment/Eligibility.htm), it appears that your wife would be eligible:

=======quote=========

Meeting Eligibility Requirements

An individual who files for unemployment insurance (UI) benefits must meet specific eligibility requirements before benefits can be paid. Individuals must:

- Have received enough wages during the base period to establish a claim.
- Be totally or **partially unemployed.**
- Be unemployed through no fault of his/her own.
- Be physically able to work.
- Be available for work which means to be ready and willing to immediately accept work.
- Be actively looking for work.
- Meet eligibility requirements each week benefits are claimed.
- Be approved for training before training benefits can be paid.